# Trajectory of an object falling towards a point mass with an initial velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion

Say you have an object that starts at a distance *r*, from a massive point-mass *m* that attracts it. This object has an initial velocity *v* tangential to said distance.

For initial velocity = zero, the trajectory is simple: it's a straight line. For any velocity larger than what is required to stay in orbit, the trajectory will be a circle, parabola, or hyperbola depending on eccentricity

What would be the trajectory of an object who's speed is too low to stay in orbit? How would you mathematically and precisely define said trajectory?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_orbit) on Kepler orbits, notably the section on the simplified two-body problem.

The article has this useful picture of the different types of orbit followed by an object interacting with a substantial point mass, and provides the corresponding equations of motion.

Note that in general, if the object remains in orbit then it follows an elliptical path (accepting a circle as an ellipse with zero eccentricity) that has the point mass at one focus.

There is no case where the object has insufficient initial speed to remain in orbit - it simply moves to a 'tighter' ellipse.

[image: illustration of Kepler orbits]

Answer (score 0):

Given  a point mass, no drag, and  any non-zero tangential velocity it will stay in orbit.

Comment: Right, I see my sign mistake in the eccentricity vector magnitude calculation. Long day, tired brain. Thanks